# How to clone specific elements from a visualforce page to another visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

Hello community I'm having an issue, i'm trying to render visualforce pages for a CV but i dont know how o render specific elements, from page 1 to page 2.

For example:
I have a blue column at the left of the CV but i dont know how to repeat only that column in the 2nd VF page.

If someone can give me a help it would be great!.

Comment: Have you considered apex:composition or apex:include tags? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_templates_intro.htm might help you create reusable layout where you just swap stuff in slots (sidebar, top menu, whatever you'll design)

Answer (score 0):

Are both Visualforce pages using the same Apex controller?

You could pass the data from one 1st page controller to 2nd page controller, then use:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!blueRows}" var="string" id="blueColumn">

    <apex:outputText value="{!blueRowValue}" id="blueValue"/><br/>

</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Actually it's one VF page, because i dont know how to make dinamic pages in VF

Comment: Even easier then. Same principle applies.